# How to make templates work with gin framework?

Tags: go, go-templates, go-gin

I am newbie to golang.
To learn it I have started with a simple web app using [gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) framework.
I have followed the gin doc & configured template file but not able to make it work. I am getting an error -

> ```
> panic: html/template: pattern matches no files: `templates/*`
>
> goroutine 1 [running]:
> html/template.Must
>   /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.2/libexec/src/html/template/template.go:330
> github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(*Engine).LoadHTMLGlob
>   /Users/ameypatil/deployment/go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/gin.go:126
> main.main()
>   /Users/ameypatil/deployment/go/src/github.com/ameykpatil/gospike/main.go:17
> ```

Below is my code -

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    //os.Setenv("GIN_MODE", "release")
    //gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)

    // Creates a gin router with default middleware:
    // logger and recovery (crash-free) middleware
    router := gin.Default()

    router.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*")
    //router.LoadHTMLFiles("templates/index.tmpl")

    router.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.tmpl", gin.H{
            "title": "GoSpike",
        })
    })

    // By default it serves on :8080 unless a
    // PORT environment variable was defined.
    router.Run(":4848")
}
```

My directory structure is

```
- gospike
--- templates
------index.tmpl
--- main.go
```

`go install` command does not give any error

but on actually running, it gives the above error. I searched & there were similar issues logged on gin's github repo but they are closed now.
I have tried various things but I guess I am missing something obvious. What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm guessing the issue is that you're using a relative filepath to access your templates.

If I compile and run your code *from the `gospike` directory*, it works fine. But if I run `gospike` from any other directory, I get the same error you were seeing.

So either you need to always run `gospike` in the parent directory of `templates`, or you need to use the absolute path. You could either hard code it:

```
router.LoadHTMLGlob("/go/src/github.com/ameykpatil/gospike/templates/*")
```

or you could do something like

```
router.LoadHTMLGlob(filepath.Join(os.Getenv("GOPATH"),
    "src/github.com/ameykpatil/gospike/templates/*"))
```

but that will fail if you have multiple paths set in your `GOPATH`. A better long-term solution might be setting a special environment variable like `TMPL_DIR`, and then just using that:

```
router.LoadHTMLGlob(filepath.Join(os.Getenv("TMPL_DIR"), "*"))
```

Answer (score 1):

use relative path glob will working, you can try to code

```golang
router.LoadHTMLGlob("./templates/*")
```

notice the `.` dot sign which meaning current directory, gin.Engine will load template
base on `templates` subdirectory of current directory .

Comment: How about dockerfiles ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it.  This walks through the directory and collects the files marked with my template suffix which is .html & then I just include all of those.  I haven't seen this answer anywhere so I thought Id post it.

```
// START UP THE ROUTER
router := gin.Default()

var files []string
filepath.Walk("./views", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if strings.HasSuffix(path, ".html") {
        files = append(files, path)
    }
    return nil
})

router.LoadHTMLFiles(files...)

// SERVE STATICS
router.Use(static.Serve("/css", static.LocalFile("./css", true)))
router.Use(static.Serve("/js", static.LocalFile("./js", true)))
router.Use(static.Serve("/images", static.LocalFile("./images", true)))

routers.LoadBaseRoutes(router)
routers.LoadBlog(router)

router.Run(":8080")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [multitemplate](https://github.com/gin-contrib/multitemplate) HTML render to support multi tempaltes.

You can use `AddFromFiles` to add multi files:

```golang
r.AddFromFiles("index", "templates/base.html", "templates/index.html")
r.AddFromFiles("article", "templates/base.html", "templates/index.html", "templates/article.html")
```

Or load multi files under a directory:

```golang
package main

import (
    "path/filepath"

    "github.com/gin-contrib/multitemplate"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.New()

    r.HTMLRender = loadTemplates()

    // ...
}

func loadTemplates() multitemplate.Render {
    files, err := filepath.Glob("template/*.tmpl")
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to load html templates: " + err.Error())
    }

    r := multitemplate.New()

    // Generate our templates map from our template/ directories
    for _, file := range files {
        r.AddFromFiles(filepath.Base(file), file)
    }

    // add other html templates directly
    r.Add("test.tmpl", someTemplate)

    return r
}
```

You could see more APIs in this repo you want, hope this post help :)